# Why the speedometer in Mig21 have 2 needles?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-instruments

How pilots are  able to read of the speed ? It's hard enough for one needle.

Comment: I don't think it did, can you please edit and post a picture of the gauge in question?

Comment: Agree with GgD. Did a Google search for "mig-21 speedometer" and went to images...  those that are labeled specifically mig-21 have one needle...

Comment: I concur, "скорость" -gauges have only one needle. As with many fighters, AoA is of more importance than exact speed.

Comment: George Geo, your question is in the process of being closed as needing details and/or clarity. It seems you may have seen a meter other than a speedometer or perhaps from a different plane or one with a non-standard configuration. Please link to whatever your source is, or attach a picture of what you saw. Once you've shown us what you were talking about, we can help you better identify it, and reopen the question.

Comment: The Q is bad, ,but still good enough to attract a pretty good answer.

Comment: @fraxinus Indeed, evidently the question was clear enough. Voting to keep open.

Comment: The answer you accepted is for the MiG-21, **why invalidate it by changing the question to the MiG-23?** [From Review](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/59455)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The normal **airspeed indicator** (showing indicated airspeed, IAS) only has one needle:

> [image: IAS]
>
> The IAS indicator (US-1600) shows Indicated Air speed up to
> 1600km/h. It has one needle (2) and one window (1). This window
> will show “1” when IAS is >1000km/h.

I think you mean the **Mach meter**, which is combined with a TAS (true airspeed) indicator:

> [image: Mach]
>
> Thick needle 1 shows the M number starting from 0,6M. Thin
> needle 2 shows the TAS starting from 600km/h (on 0,6 mark).
> Scale indication follows this logic.

---

Source: Flight Manual for the DCS (Digital Combat Simulator) [MiG-21](https://www.digitalcombatsimulator.com/en/shop/modules/mig21bis/) by Leatherneck Simulations

Comment: I looked at the answers and by mistake I put the Mig21 21 in the title. I was Mig23 about.

Comment: @GeorgeGeo Sorry, but you cannot fundamentally change the question after it has received an answer. Please ask a new question and please include an image of what you are talking about so we don't have to guess.